# What is the limit of $\frac{x}{x+y}$ as $x$ and $y$ tends to infinity

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus, functions

I am relatively new to limits of 2 or more variables function.

Given that $z =\frac{x}{x+y}$. What is the limit of $z$ when $x$ and $y$ tends to infinity?

Is there a l'hopital's rule for 2 or more variables?

Comment: The limit does not exist.

Comment: It depends on how fast they increase relative to each other : any values  from $0$ ($y$ much bigger than $x$) to $1$ ($x$ much bigger than $y$) are possible once they are both positive

Comment: x and y may tend to infinity in a multitude of different ways, producing different results.

Comment: $z=\frac 1 {1+y/x}$ and you know nothing about the behavior of $\frac y x$.

Comment: You recieved 3 answers to your question. Is any of them what you needed? If so, consider accepting the best answer and upvoting all useful answers you got. That's how the site works.

Comment: @5xum Sorry I can't, I need 15 reputation points.

Comment: @KohYiMinJason You do not need any rep to accept an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While the above answers are great for rigorously understanding why a limit cannot exist, it may be nice to see a simple example. For the concept of a limit to exist, any such limit must be unique. Let $y = 2x$. Then,
$$\lim_{x,y \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{x + y} =  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{x + 2x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{3x} = \frac{1}{3},$$
since as $x \rightarrow \infty$, we also have $y \rightarrow \infty$ and vice versa. Now suppose $y = 3x$. Now we have
$$\lim_{x,y \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{x + y} =  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{x + 3x} = \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{x}{4x} = \frac{1}{4},$$
so the 'limit' is not unique. Hence, it does not exist.

Answer (score 3):

Your question cannot be answered, because it is not formed correctly. In particular, it is unclear what you mean when you say "when $x$ and $y$ tend to infinity".

Let me explain. In single variable functions, there exist two **separate, but related concepts**.

1. The concept of a limit **at a point** is defined as $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$$ being the value $L$ such that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$.
2. The concept of a limit **at infinity** is defined as $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$$ being the value $L$ such that, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $M\in\mathbb R$ such that if $x>M$, then $|f(x)-L| < \epsilon$.

In single variables, the two concepts are quite similar to each other, but here is the catch: *Only one of them can be generalized to higher dimensions*. Indeed, the first concept of a limit at a point can be defined whenever you have a function between two spaces on which you can talk about a "distance" (these are called metric spaces and are very important in mathematics). The generalized definition would then be

> The limit $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$$ is equal to $L$ if, for every $\epsilon >0$, there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that, if the distance between $x$ and $a$ is smaller than $\delta$, then the distance between $f(x)$ and $L$ is smaller than $\epsilon$.

Notice that this definition is a direct generalization of the definition 1 above, if you take $|x-y|$ to be the definition of distance between $x$ and $y$.

However, a similar generalization **cannot** be made of the second definition of the limit. If your space allows you to speak of "magnitudes" of elements (i.e., it is a normed space), then the best thing you can define is the following:

> The limit $$\lim_{x\to\infty} f(x)$$ is equal to $L$ if and only if, for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $M\in\mathbb R$ such that if the magnitude of $x$ is greater than $M$, then the magnitude of $f(x)-L$ (or, "the distance between $f(x)$ and $L$) is smaller than $\epsilon$.

However this definition is not a direct generalization of definition 2 above. In particular, this definition, applied to single variable functions, does not distinguish between a limit at positive and a limit at negative infinity.

---

Still, we can apply this weaker definition of "limit at infinity", we can see that the limit $$\lim_{(x,y)\to\infty} \frac{x}{x+y}$$ actually **does not exist**. This is because no matter how big $(x,y)$ is, you cannot say anything about what the value of $\frac{x}{x+y}$ is. For example, even assuming that $\|(x,y)\|>M$, we can have $(x_1,y_1) = (0, M+1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)=(M+1, 0)$, and we then have $f(x_1,y_1)=0$ and $f(x_2, y_2)=1$, so a limit cannot exist.

---

**Note**: this is personal preference, but just to avoid confusion, I would actually write this "weaker" limit at infinity as
$$\lim_{\|(x,y)\|\to\infty} f(x)$$ as to make it clear that we are pushing the magnitude to $\infty$.

Comment: I deleted my first comment because I was not so sure of it any longer. May be $\lim_{x,y\to\infty}$ should not be understood as $\lim_{\|(x,y)\|\to+\infty}$ but rather as $\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty,\infty)}?$ Anyway, one can also find examples (like $y=x$ and $y=2x$) proving that even $\lim_{(x,y)\to(+\infty,+\infty)}\frac x{x+y}$ does not exist.

Comment: @AnneBauval $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(\infty, \infty)}$$ needs some explanation. How exactly would you define such a limit? What would be the $\epsilon,\delta$ definition of it? Would you say that "for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists some $M\in\mathbb R$ such that if $x>M$ and $y>M$, then $|f(x,y)-L| < \epsilon$? That would actually be quite a decent definition, come to think of it.

Comment: $\lim_{(x,y)\to(a,b)}f(x,y)=L\iff\forall\varepsilon>0\quad\exists\delta>0\quad(D((x,y),(a,b))<\delta\implies|f(x,y)-L|<\epsilon),$ where e.g. $D((x,y),(a,b)):=d(x,a)+d(y,b),$ and $d(x,\infty):=\frac1{1+|x|}.$

Comment: I was editing my previous comment while you were completing yours. I can see we agree (except that you focused on $+\infty$ and I on $\pm\infty$). I do not undertstand whether "come to think of it" means "you should..." or "I shall" (english is not my mother language), but never mind: I want to stop.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I would like to ask, if I were to plot a graph $z = \frac{x}{x + y}$, as I keep increasing x and y together, $z$ will approach $z=0.5$. Could I say that as $x$ and $y$ approaches infinity towards the direction of the position vector $\vec{v} = x\hat{i} + y\hat{j}$, $z$ will tends towards $z = 0.5$?

Comment: @KohYiMinJason It depends on "how" you increase $x$ and $y$ together. For example, if you increase $x$ by $1$, and increase $y$ by $2$ in each step, then you will not get $z$ to be around $0.5$, but instead you will get around $\frac13$. Or, if you increase $x$ more quickly, then you might even get $1$. Or if you increase $y$ more quikly, then you get $0$.

Comment: @5xum 

Thanks, for your clarification, Suppose if I want to increase $x$ by $1$ step and $y$ by $1$ step respectively, how would I show that the limit as $x$ and $y$ tends towards infinity in that direction for $z = \frac{x}{x + y}$ is $0.5$?

Comment: @KohYiMinJason Well if you increase them both the same, then $x=A+s$ and $y=B+s$, where $s$ is the number of steps. In that case, $$\frac{x}{x+y} = \frac{A+s}{B+2s} = \frac{\frac As + 1}{\frac Bs + 2}$$ obviously tends to $\frac12$ as $s$ becomes large.

Comment: Thinking about Cauchy sequences recalled be this (now "old") discussion. I pop up here just to mention that the way we agreed to define $\lim_{(x,y)\to(+\infty,+\infty)}$ coincides with the usual one in a definition of Cauchy sequences by $\lim_{p,q\to\infty}d(x_p,x_q)=0.$

Answer (score 1):

The limit of $z$ cannot be known unless we know some relation between $x$ and $y$.

$z = \frac{x}{x + y}$ can be written as $z = \frac{1}{1+\frac{y}{x}}$

As you can see, the value of $z$ depends on the ratio $\frac{y}{x}$

While both $x$ and $y$ tend to infinity, their ratio might still converge. The limit of $z$ will exist only if the limit of $\frac{y}{x}$ exists.

Comment: @Henry You're right. I've now edited my answer to include the criterion of the ratio converging.